# ajax POST request fails to consume .Net Web API

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, webapi

I have a web api controller with action "Create"

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] Transaction tran)
    {
        tran.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
         await _db.Transactions.AddAsync(tran);
        var result = await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
         
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Now when i create a html file with js script inside to consume it with use of ajax, as per below

```
    $("#button").on("click",function(){
    var tran =  {userId: "68a60d7d-e323-472f-a3d6-7df1babbd633",  amount: "100.67",  businessName: "TESLA",  transactionPurpose: "Electrical Vehicle" };
      $.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json",   
               data: tran,
               url:"https://localhost:7143/api/Transaction/Create",
               success:function(data)
               {
                   alert('API resut is Success');
                   console.log(data);
              },
             error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         console.log('Error in Operation');
                     }
            });
});
```

i get a 400 error in my google chrome console that reads as below

```
{type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",…}
errors: {$: ["'u' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],…}
$: ["'u' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."]
0: "'u' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
tran: ["The tran field is required."]
0: "The tran field is required."
status: 400
title: "One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId: "00-4156aea880b9869412d44dd83f4889a5-286644919e844504-00"
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
```

ajax works fine with Get requests from my API controller(i have tested).
I have also tried to wrap the tran object in many different ways and it does not work.
I have been looking at ajax documentations from jquery and it still does not explain where the error coming from.

When i use swagger for my api the successful POST request looks like below

> curl -X 'POST' \   'https://localhost:7143/api/Transaction/Create' \
> -H 'accept: */*' \   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \   -d '{   "userId": "68a60d7d-e323-472f-a3d6-7df1babbd633",   "amount": "120",
> "businessName": "Tesla",   "transactionPurpose": "ModelT" }'

and the below swagger response header

> access-control-allow-origin: *   content-type: application/json;
> charset=utf-8   date: Wed,17 Aug 2022 09:53:31 GMT   server: Kestrel

can you please help me to get on the right direction ? how does my Web api posts ok with swagger but when i try and do the same with jquery ajax - it fails - please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your api expect a json string in the body.
Try to stringify the content

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",   
        data: JSON.stringify(tran),
```